# 2 query strings in one select in a GET form

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way I can use a form like this:

```
      <form method="get" action="/recipes">
        <select>
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </form>
```

to redirect the user to `/recipes?from=13-07-2020&to=19-07-2020`?
 I.e both "from" and "to" in one select.

Comment: So, one of `from` or `to` is the shown select, and the other one will be calculated, right? You can use a hidden field, and recalculate it then the visible one changes

Comment: @Pac0 how do you mean? Can you post an example please?

Comment: @CedricHadjian Using Javascript, listen onto the `change` event for the select element. `event.target.value` would have the selected value, use that to set the value of a hidden input field.

Comment: @JonathanRosa Ok, I guess I can achieve this using `data-*`, I hope there's a better way of doing this, without javascript.

Comment: what values are in option?

Comment: @Vaibhav something like `2020-07-06` and `2020-07-12`, `from` and `to` respectively.

Comment: @Vaibhav so that once the user clicks on the option, it redirects the browser to `recipes/from=2020-07-06&to=2020-07-12`

Comment: check this [link](https://imxwn.csb.app/) , check it source code. I hope you need this. I am using example values. 

Press the save and see the URL data

Comment: As per @Pac0 I am using hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a 'Select' field, I used a 'date' input field, but as long as the value can be parsed correctly by `Date.parse()`, this approach could work :

- User is shown one of the field (example: the "from" date), and can choose the value
- When the value is changed, the other field (here : the "to" field) is updated accordingly. This other field is part of the form, but hidden.

See in the dev console the request

```js
function calculateTo(dateFrom) {
  if (dateFrom){
    newDateTo = addDays(dateFrom, 6);
  }
  else {
    newDateTo = null;
  }

  document.getElementById('toDate').value = newDateTo.toISOString().substring(0,10);
}
        
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="/recipes">
  <label for="FromDate">From date: </label>
  <input id="fromDate" name= "from" type="date" value="2020-06-13" onchange="calculateTo(this.value)"/>
  <input id="toDate" name="to" type="string"  value="2020-06-19" hidden="true" />
  <button action="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

There might be a simpler way (and missing null checks etc.), but the output seems to be what you expect :

[image: The submit request is produced as expected]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I solved it like this, which uses jQuery and could also be solved through plain JS, of course.
HTML:

```
<select id="select-week">
  <option data-from="06-07-2020" data-to="12-07-2020">Recipes from 06-07-2020 to 12-07-2020</option>
  <option data-from="13-07-2020" data-to="19-07-2020">Recipes from 13-07-2020 to 19-07-2020</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#select-week").change(function () {
  const from = $(this).find(":selected").data("from");
  const to = $(this).find(":selected").data("to");
  location.href = `/recipes?from=${from}&to=${to}`;
});
```